# Having problem with andSelf() while reading O'Reillys jQuery Cookbook

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get refreshed on jQuery so I bought O'Reillys jQuery cookbook. I'm having trouble with the exercise on using andSelf() to manipulate the parent of the selected element; though my code is exactly like the books.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script>
        $('div').find('p').andSelf().css('border', '1px solid #993300');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

From my understanding my jQuery should add a border to the div but it doesn't. When I remove andSelf() it does add a border to the 2 p tags though. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That book was originally released in 2009 so there's likely to be quite a few things that are now deprecated/removed. If you want to use that book to learn I'd strongly suggest you double check each method it mentions in the docs to ensure they are still in use: https://api.jquery.com. Be wary of `live()`, `bind()`, `delegate()`, `toggle()` (as an event handler), `load()` (as an event hanlder) and `$.browser` as they are the main ones to avoid these days.

Comment: Hmm..alright. Well thank you for the heads up. It's been years since I was actively developing. How far certain things have come is pretty cool. Back when I was still developing full time...XML was pretty standard...JSON seems to have replaced XML as the industry standard. Certain litttle things I've observed are pretty cool. I've got to get up to date in a hurry.

Comment: Indeed, JSON has taken over. Microsoft were the last holdouts for XML, but even they have caved to JSON in the last few years

Comment: It's so much better. Though, there are a few things I've hated in life...geometry, fractions....and working with complex arrays lol. I need to get better at working with arrays in PHP; but it's always something I've wanted to do. I just don't think I ever found a good source for taking a deeper dive into them. Constructing a 1 or even 2 dimensional array isn't hard. It's the filtering, sorting, and restructuring of arrays I have issues with sometimes.

Comment: I only mention that because it's necessary to output the JSON in the way I need...depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In the jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/andSelf/):

> This API has been removed in jQuery 3.0; use
>   [`.addBack()`](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/) instead, which should
>   work identically.

```js
$(function() {

    $('div').find('p').addBack().css('border', '1px solid #993300');

});
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know you could run JS in StackOverflow like this.

Answer (score 2):

This method is deprecated and removed.

> This API has been removed in jQuery 3.0; use .addBack() instead, which should work identically.

https://api.jquery.com/andSelf/

Comment: That did it. Thanks. Hopefully there aren't a bunch of other depreciated functions in it...I thought I got the most recent version.